# How do I use SBCL sb-alien to create a Gtk4 window open it and have a simple callback that works?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ffi, sbcl, gtk4

The documentation is difficult to understand.
http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Foreign-Function-Interface

Part of the problem is not understanding how to implement this type
https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/callback.Callback.html
in my code.

I need an example that works. I could not make this example adapt to Gtk4.

https://www.reddit.com/r/lisp/comments/a31oxr/demo_sbcl_script_using_gtk/

### my present attempt

```
;;; test1

(cl:in-package "CL-USER") ; which USEs package "SB-ALIEN"

(load-shared-object
 "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-4.so.1.600.6")

(define-alien-routine gtk_application_new (* t) (app (* t)) (flags (* T)))

(define-alien-routine g_object_unref void  (win (* t)))

(define-alien-routine gtk_application_new (* t) (txt c-string) (flags int))

(define-alien-routine g_application_run int
  (app (* t)) (argc int) (argv (* t)))

(define-alien-routine g_signal_connect long
  (instance (* t))
  (sig c-string)
  ;(cback (function void (* t) (* t))) ; stuck at correct callback
  (alien-funcall  (cback (function void)))
  (data (* t)))

(define-alien-callable app_activate void
    (with-alien ((void))
      (format t "application is activated")))

(with-alien ((app (* t)) (status int))
  (setf app (gtk_application_new "test1.app.gtk" 0))
  (g_signal_connect app "activate"
                    (alien-callable-function 'app_activate)
                    nil)
  (setf status (g_application_run  app 0 nil))
  (g_object_unref app)
  ;; return status
  status)
```

### the error

```
> ;   caught 1 ERROR condition While evaluating the form starting at
> line 24, column 0   of
> #P"/home/jacek/Programming/Lisp/lispy-experiments/aliengtk4/test1.lisp":
> 
> debugger invoked on a SB-INT:COMPILED-PROGRAM-ERROR in thread
> #<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10010A0003}>:   Execution of a form compiled with errors. Form:   (SB-ALIEN::ALIEN-LAMBDA VOID
>     (WITH-ALIEN ((VOID))
>       (FORMAT T "application is activated"))) Compile-time error:   during macroexpansion of (SB-ALIEN::ALIEN-LAMBDA VOID
>     (WITH-ALIEN #
>       #)). Use *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* to intercept.
> 
>  The value    WITH-ALIEN  is not of type    LIST
```

### Gtk3 working example

```
;;; test2

(load-shared-object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.2404.29")

;; This will exclude :divide-by-zero which might be caused in the GTK lib.
;; The default traps are (:OVERFLOW :INVALID :DIVIDE-BY-ZERO).
;; See: (sb-int:get-floating-point-modes)
(sb-int:set-floating-point-modes :traps '(:overflow :invalid))


(define-alien-routine gtk_application_window_new (* t) (app (* t)))

(define-alien-routine gtk_application_new (* t) (txt c-string) (flags int))

(define-alien-routine g_application_run int
  (app (* t)) (argc int) (argv (* t)))

(define-alien-routine g_signal_connect_data long
  (instance (* t)) (sig c-string)
  (cback (function void (* t) (* t)))
  (data (* t)) (unusedptr (* t)) (unusedint int))

(define-alien-routine gtk_window_set_title void (win (* t)) (ttl (c-string)))

(define-alien-routine gtk_window_set_default_size void
  (win (* t)) (x int) (y int))

(define-alien-routine gtk_widget_show_all void (win (* t)))

(sb-alien::define-alien-callable mycallback void ((app (* t)) (u (* t)))
                                 (with-alien ((win (* t)))
                                   (setf win (gtk_application_window_new app))
                                   (gtk_window_set_title win "This is windoe")
                                   (gtk_window_set_default_size win 100 100)
                                   (gtk_widget_show_all win)))


(with-alien ((app (* t)) (status int))
  (setf app (gtk_application_new "org.gtk.example" 0))
  (g_signal_connect_data app "activate" (alien-callable-function  'mycallback) nil nil 0)
  (g_application_run app 0 nil))

(format t "App finished successfully~%")
```

### sbcl version

sbcl --version
SBCL 2.2.11.160-65fe8bb77

Answer (score 3):

To find the solution with imperfect SBCL documentation I had to grep the source folder of SBCL and the quicklisp folder. That allowed me to find more examples of the usage of with-alien, define-alien-callable, alien-callable-function and other functions used here.

Also playing with the Gtk3 example and adapting it to the current SBCL and getting rid of the private function call allowed me to make progress.

I tried to implement the getting started example, only with little modification.
https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/getting_started.html

### still unanswered

The Gtk4 documentation uses **g_signal_connect** but I use **g_signal_connect_data**. I still can't figure out how to use g_signal_connect in my code. I suspect it is because in gsignal.h g_signal_connect is not a real function but a C preprocessor directive.

### working code

```
;; calling from terminal
;; sbcl --noinform --load ~/Programming/Lisp/lispy-experiments/aliengtk4/test1.lisp

(cl:in-package "CL-USER") ; which USEs package "SB-ALIEN"

;; This will exclude :divide-by-zero which might be caused in the GTK lib.
;; The default traps are (:OVERFLOW :INVALID :DIVIDE-BY-ZERO).
;; See: (sb-int:get-floating-point-modes)
;; this error apparently happens when we have no widgets on the window
(sb-int:set-floating-point-modes :traps '(:overflow :invalid))

(load-shared-object
 "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-4.so.1.600.6")

;;; calling Gtk4 library functions
(define-alien-routine gtk_application_new (* t) (app (* t)) (flags (* T)))

(define-alien-routine g_object_unref void  (win (* t)))

(define-alien-routine gtk_application_new (* t) (txt c-string) (flags int))

(define-alien-routine g_application_run int (app (* t)) (argc int) (argv (* t)))

(define-alien-routine g_signal_connect_data long
  (instance (* t))
  (sig c-string)
  (cback (function void  (* t) (* t)))
  (data (* t))
  (unusedptr (* t)) (unusedint int))

(define-alien-routine gtk_application_window_new (* t) (app (* t)))

(define-alien-routine gtk_window_set_title void (win (* t)) (ttl (c-string)))

(define-alien-routine gtk_window_set_default_size void
                      (win (* t)) (x int) (y int))

(define-alien-routine gtk_widget_show void (win (* t)))

;;; define callback
(define-alien-callable app_activate void ((app (* t)) (u (* t)))
                       (with-alien ((window (* t)))
                                   (format t "application is activated")
                                   (setf window (gtk_application_window_new app))
                                   (gtk_window_set_title window "This is Gtk4 window")
                                   (gtk_window_set_default_size window 300 100)
                                   (gtk_widget_show window)))

;;; run gtk4 app
;; https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/getting_started.html
(defun try-gtk ()
  (with-alien ((app (* t)) (status int))
              (setf app (gtk_application_new "test1.app.gtk" 0))
              (g_signal_connect_data app "activate"
                                     (alien-callable-function 'app_activate)
                                     nil
                                     nil
                                     0)
              (setf status (g_application_run  app 0 nil))
              (g_object_unref app)
              ;; return status
              status))

(try-gtk)
```